# gem problems with snow leopard and nokogiri bluecloth and feedzirra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nokogiri, bluecloth, feedzirra

I just upgraded to snow leopard, ran the migration assistant and have spent hours and hours trying to get these gems to work with no luck. When I try to start my server I get the errors below. All the gems that are missing are actually in vendor dir. This works on another persons snow leopard so it must be an artifact of me migrating from leopard or something else I messed up today.

I have tried rake gems:build:force. Tried deleting the .bundles manually. I also removed mac ports, reinstalled and did: sudo port install libxml2 libxslt. Also installed xcode.

```
 ruby script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
dlsym(0x103a010a0, Init_bluecloth_ext): symbol not found - /Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/bluecloth-2.0.5/lib/bluecloth_ext.bundle
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/bluecloth-2.0.5/lib/bluecloth_ext.bundle
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/bluecloth-2.0.5/lib/bluecloth.rb:156
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/environment.rb:12
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
dlsym(0x1026a0790, Init_nokogiri): symbol not found - /Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:13
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/environment.rb:12
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
dlsym(0x103998840, Init_nokogiri): symbol not found - /Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:13
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/sax-machine-0.0.14/lib/sax-machine/sax_document.rb:1
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/sax-machine-0.0.14/lib/sax-machine.rb:5
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/feedzirra-0.0.23/lib/feedzirra.rb:5
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/environment.rb:12
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
dlsym(0x102690920, Init_bluecloth_ext): symbol not found - /Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/bluecloth-2.0.5/lib/bluecloth_ext.bundle
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/bluecloth-2.0.5/lib/bluecloth_ext.bundle
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/bluecloth-2.0.5/lib/bluecloth.rb:156
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:169:in `process'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/environment.rb:12
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
dlsym(0x1026a7a80, Init_nokogiri): symbol not found - /Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:13
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:169:in `process'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/environment.rb:12
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
dlsym(0x102ab4c00, Init_nokogiri): symbol not found - /Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/nokogiri-1.4.1/lib/nokogiri.rb:13
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/sax-machine-0.0.14/lib/sax-machine/sax_document.rb:1
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/sax-machine-0.0.14/lib/sax-machine.rb:5
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/gems/feedzirra-0.0.23/lib/feedzirra.rb:5
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:169:in `process'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/config/environment.rb:12
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Users/jnylund/Projects/vente/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
Missing these required gems:
  bluecloth  = 2.0.5
  nokogiri  = 1.4.1
  feedzirra  = 0.0.23

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.174 at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.5 at /Users/jnylund/.gem/ruby/1.8, /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8, /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took 2 days of trial and error, but I seem to have things working, im not exactly sure what cured the problem, but here is my best guess:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64 rake gems:build:force
```

I think this is what finally fixed it.

I did also clean up all my system gems using:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64 gem pristine --all
```

So its possible one of these gems depends on a gem in my system and that helped also.

Joel

Comment: When you *upgrade* to Snow Leopard, your native extensions previously compiled for i386 Macs need to be recompiled for X64, because Snow Leopard is 64-bit. That's why forcing the rebuild helped.

Answer (score 1):

Can I recommend RVM?

http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Its an amazing tool for managing your Ruby installations and just cuts out 99.999% of all hassle related to installing or upgrading Ruby.

It also allows you to have any version of Ruby installed on your system *simultaneously* with a single command and it cuts out almost all need for sudoing. I've found it to be pretty seamless in terms of performance, usage and deployment as its very well supported by the creator.

The beauty of RVM is that is stores all gems within its own directory structure for each version of Ruby that you have installed, meaning you don't need to worry about paths at all ( other than on initial setup, but thats all documented within the installer )

Comment: I did use rvm before, but was worried that was part of my problem in moving from snow leopard. Im actually not changing ruby version, just operating system.

Comment: I highly recommend using RVM with Snow Leopard. Use RVM to install  1.8.7 and a 1.9.2 Rubies, so you can bounce back and forth, then copy your gems using RVM's gemset copy command from the system 1.8.7 to your newly installed ones. That way your system Ruby stays pristine and you are working within the RVM sandboxes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem with vendoring your gems: your native gems will often not be portable from one machine to another, or after upgrading your operating system. Your vendored gems certainly won't work on Linux or Windows.

What you need to do is clear out your gems and re-compile - the equivalent of `gem pristine all`. Clearing out your `vendor/gems` and re-vendoring may solve the problem. But I'd highly recommend switching to [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) for managing your gem dependencies. It works great on 2.3.5.

If you're still having problems using these gems when they are installed via normal means (e.g. do `gem install nokogiri`, then try `irb -rrubygems -rnokogiri`) then you definitely have a bigger problem. Hard to say what that would be. Anything from your installation of XCode is buggered to a hardware problem.